# How to reference a cell in VBA that's dependent on a date value

Tags: vba, excel

I need to update daily volumes calculated from one sheet to a table with historical data.

For example: In sheet 1 I have a date in 1 cell and a value in the adjacent cell. In another sheet I have several columns with the column A being dates and the rest of the columns filled with data.

I need a macro that references the date in sheet 1, and pastes the value in sheet 2 in column B that corresponds to the date in sheet 1.

This is the code I'm using now but it's not efficient.

The date that I'm looking up is in sheet1 cell(1,2) Datematch is basically a numeric value that counts how far down I'll need to offset in sheet2 and DateValues is the value that I'm trying to enter in column B

I want to do this without using the Datematch value

```
Sub testing()
Set Datematch = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)
Set DateValues = Sheet1.Cells(2, 2)
Sheet2.Activate
Range("A1").Offset(Datematch, 1).Value = DateValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Might be easier to just to a Index(match) , copy/paste ...Otherwise , have you tried anything ? Basically you will need to pull the first column into an array, then the data on the 2nd sheet into an array then run some matching loops

Comment: currently i'm just manually entering the information in the corresponding cell.  The thing is that i am trying to dummy proof this thing so someone else can run it while i'm away.
I guess another way to ask this question is how do i select a cell in sheet 2 column A that has chronological dates that corresponds to a date value in lets say cell 1,1 in sheet 1. in VBA though

Comment: well i am happy to help you with it, if you want to throw some code up there, i don't know your level of VBA, but this is fair simple

Comment: i have a very basic VBA skills, i added the code i have above.  it works it is just not efficient since i have to use the match formula in sheet 1 to count the number of rows. i know i can do this in VBA, but my mind is just mush right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

James Let me throw this too you to give you something to work with and then come back with another question when you need help (don't want to figure the whole project out for you)

short hand code:

```
Sub FindStuff()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim VariableToLookUp() as Variant 'i used all variants because i don't know what data you have
Dim Results() as Variant 
Dim VariableWithValues() as Variant
Dim I,II as long

Redim Results(UBound(VariableToLookUp))

Set VariableToLookUp Range(Cell(1,1),Cell(LastRow,1) 
Set VariableWithValues Sheet2.Range(Cell(1,1),Cell(LastRow,2) 'this gets column2

For I = 0 to UBound(VariableToLookUp)
    For II = 0 to UBound(VariableWithValues)
        If VariableToLookup(I,1) = VariableWithValues(II,1) Then
              Results(I) = VariableWithValues(II,2)
              exit for
        endIf
    next
next

Sheet1.Range("B2").Activate
For I = 0 to Ubound(Results)
     ActiveCell.Offset(I,0).Value = Results(I)
next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
)
```

Now keep in mind a few things ...1 i did not test this since i hope it to be more of guide to get you to the next question. and 2 I may have the wrong syntax but i promise the right ideas or close enough. If you post another question respond to this one with a link so i can find it
.. As a side note, if you can set both to tables or add a logic to sort them in some order you can get real complex search features to speed them up, I have had to check 3MM+ numbers against 90K in VBA so had to come up with some index logic

Answer (score 1):

This seems like something that could be solved with a [Lookup function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Lookup-and-reference-functions-reference-8aa21a3a-b56a-4055-8257-3ec89df2b23e). Look at the VLOOKUP or the HLOOKUP. Or, if you want to learn an advanced method, use [INDEX(MATCH())](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/).

Answer (score 1):

Depends how and how often this Source sheet is updated, there will be different better solution. Since you didn't say how the source data is updated, I assume it's one off thing where new data will be on different sheet.

You may not need a macro at all based on what you have in hand.
 - Name the source data range (static or dynamic), say **SourceRange**
 - Ensure they are sorted in Ascending order (can be done in macro)
 - Then in the Col B of the other sheet, use formula 
**`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(<col A>,SourceRange,2,FALSE),0)`**

To illustrate, I have put all in one sheet:
[image: illustration]

And since you did not mention how the historical data is stored when updated, nothing has done.

The approach will change based on how the source data is updated/retrieved and what to do with the old data.

Comment: Yeah, I was going that way but he said no formula, had to be "dummy proof this thing so someone else can run it while i'm away"

Comment: Thanks @HolmesIV, to make this dummy proof, there is a lot of work. Not to mention hiding and protecting Worksheets and Ranges. To me if a daily update is required, I would have the Daily fresh data on individual file and use VBS to transfer new data to the historical file. Can set up a batch file to execute the VBS and set that to Task Scheduler, the VBS will check for update files and act on it if required. Too bad I don't have the joy to implement it...

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't figure out how to work around using a cheat value i.e. DateRow which basically is just a match function that returns me what row my date is in.

```
Sub InventoryUpdate()

Set DateRow = Sheets("Inputs").Cells(40, 8)
Set DateValues = Sheets("Inputs").Range("B40:F40")

DateValues.Copy
Sheets("Inventory").Activate
Range("A1").Offset(DateRow - 1, 30).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```